# Grails unit test, mock method 'mockFor()' doesn't work quite well

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails

It seems the Grails unit test utils method mockFor doesn't work quite as it said in the document.

```
def strictControl = mockFor(MyService)
strictControl.demand.someMethod(0..2) { String arg1, int arg2 -> … }
strictControl.demand.static.aStaticMethod {-> … }
```

> Notice that you can mock static as well as instance methods by using
>   the "static" property. You then specify the name of the method to
>   mock, with an optional range argument. This range determines how many
>   times you expect the method to be called, and if the number of
>   invocations falls outside of that range (either too few or too many)
>   then an assertion error will be thrown. If no range is specified, a
>   default of "1..1" is assumed, i.e. that the method must be called
>   exactly once.

However, in my method under test, I have a condition to call someMethod, if true call someMethod, else not call. If it goes into the positive condition (which means call someMethod).

In my test I have a mock like following:

```
def strictControl = mockFor(MyService)
strictControl.demand.someMethod(0..0) { String arg1, int arg2 -> … }
```

`'0..0'` from what I am understanding from document means someMethod should be called zero time (never called). My test still passed.

I don't know why the times invoked called match exactly.

Comment: I don't understand.  So, when the test is run, is `someMethod` called, and it still passes?  Or what?

Comment: Have you verified the mockControl? `strictControl.verify()` in the end of test. Also it is not mentioned where `createMock()` is called on mock control. I hope you do. :)

Comment: @dmahapatro I did something like: service.xxxMethod = strictControl.createMock()